# Azure devops pipeline get work items between builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm looking for a pre-made option to take 2 builds, and compare the work items or PRs completed between them.  i know there are REST API options in order to find out this information ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 ) , but i would rather not build my own app for this if one already exists.  Is there something built into azure devops that shows this information, preferably in an exportable format?  Is there possibly an existing devops extension in the store?  Any searching i do just brings up the REST API call and nothing else unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They seem to have changed it in Azure DevOps. We are using Azure DevOps **Server** (on-prem). In it, the old TFS-like work items comparison between the builds is possible when you actually deploy (execute a release) in a stage:

(*in the screenshot below the right popup pane is showing the work item "diff" between the build currently deployed in TEST and the one which is about to be deployed now*)

[image]

Comment: that's great!  Almost exactly what i was looking for.  if there was a way to filter/export that data, then that would be it absolutely.  But so far much closer than anything else i've found.  Thank you.

Comment: Great functionnality. It's a shame you can't get the same thing using the new azureDevops Yml pipelines...

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to it being generated at build time, you could look at using the [Generate Release Notes Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-GenerateReleaseNotes-Task) from the marketplace.

Comment: that is nice, absolutely, but if you have multiple builds it could be a little difficult to drill down into each build artifact, find the release note and extract it, and then add to a global one for all the builds we're interested in.

Comment: The same task you can use for releases.  From what I remember for releases, it uses the current deployed build on a stage compared to what you are deploying to get that list.  There is some limitations in ADO though that it only shows work items for the primary artifact, so probably won't work if you having multiple artifacts defined on a release pipeline.  It can also be a little difficult to recreate the release notes because you have to do several mock deployments.  At my old company we tried to find an out of box solution to what you are asking for but had to build our own.